# aiohttp: AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'get_extra_info' using HTTPS_PROXY sand trust_env=True

Tags: python, aiohttp, http-proxy

Trying to connect using ENV proxy:

```
    if self.websession is None:
        # self.websession = aiohttp.ClientSession(trace_configs=[trace_config])
        self.websession = aiohttp.ClientSession(trace_configs=[trace_config], trust_env=True)
    _LOGGER.debug("New connection prepared")
```

and invoking using

```
https_proxy=http://localhost:9090 python3 cli.py
```

gives

```
  File "/opt/homebrew/lib/python3.11/site-packages/aiohttp/client.py", line 1141, in __aenter__
    self._resp = await self._coro
                ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/opt/homebrew/lib/python3.11/site-packages/aiohttp/client.py", line 536, in _request
    conn = await self._connector.connect(
          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/opt/homebrew/lib/python3.11/site-packages/aiohttp/connector.py", line 540, in connect
    proto = await self._create_connection(req, traces, timeout)
            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/opt/homebrew/lib/python3.11/site-packages/aiohttp/connector.py", line 899, in _create_connection
    _, proto = await self._create_proxy_connection(req, traces, timeout)
              ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/opt/homebrew/lib/python3.11/site-packages/aiohttp/connector.py", line 1325, in _create_proxy_connection
    return await self._start_tls_connection(
          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/opt/homebrew/lib/python3.11/site-packages/aiohttp/connector.py", line 1124, in _start_tls_connection
    tls_proto.connection_made(
  File "/opt/homebrew/lib/python3.11/site-packages/aiohttp/base_protocol.py", line 62, in connection_made
    tcp_nodelay(tr, True)
  File "/opt/homebrew/lib/python3.11/site-packages/aiohttp/tcp_helpers.py", line 25, in tcp_nodelay
    sock = transport.get_extra_info("socket")
          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'get_extra_info'
ERROR:asyncio:Unclosed client session
client_session: <aiohttp.client.ClientSession object at 0x102259090>
```

with aiohttp 3.8. Without trust_env everything is fine. Proxy is running and accessible.

**UPDATE**

It does not make a difference if I add a transport or not:

```
self.websession = aiohttp.ClientSession(trace_configs=[trace_config], trust_env=True, connector=aiohttp.TCPConnector())
```

Comment: `transport` seems to be `None`

Comment: I'm not a python guy- do I need a transport to use a proxy?

Comment: This looks a lot like https://github.com/aio-libs/aiohttp/issues/6239